# Once banner drops down, remove logo

Tags: html, css, image

As it is right now, my website has a logo on the top left. This is specified by the `img` tag in the HTML

[image: http://i.imgur.com/A1bvZ4e.png]

Now when the user scrolls down, a banner is revealed, as indicted by the CSS `#header.reveal`

[image: http://i.imgur.com/CGPTEmv.png]

The goal is to shrink the image once the bar is revealed.

I'm trying to do this by adding a `background-image` to my css with the same image, just a larger percentage. And to then remove the `img` tag by trying to use `content:none;` on the `SwoleCakesPicLogo` ID

But as you can see, I tried to do that but now both of the images are there, the bigger one is just covering the smaller one.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/yLfzG3s.png]

**If you guys have any idea on how I can remove the bigger image once the bar is revealed, that would be great**

Here is my css

```
#header.reveal {
    -moz-animation: reveal-header 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation: reveal-header 0.5s;
    -o-animation: reveal-header 0.5s;
    -ms-animation: reveal-header 0.5s;
    animation: reveal-header 0.5s;
    background-image:url(../images/Swole-Cakes-LogoText.png), url(../images/SwoleCakesText.png);
    background-size: 3%, 15%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position:5%, 50%, 50%, 50%;
}

#header.reveal #SwoleCakesPicLogo

{
    content:none;   
}
```

**I have also tried replacing `content:none;` with `display:none;`. When I do that, the bigger image does not appear at all from the start.**

Here is my HTML

```
<header id="header" class="alt">
  <h1 id="logo"><a href="#index" class="scrolly"><img id="SwoleCakesPicLogo" src="images/Swole-Cakes-LogoText.png" alt="SwoleCakesLogo" style="width:10%;"/></a></h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Yes I have, I forgot to write that in. But when I do that, the big logo just never appears

Comment: But when I load up the page for the first time, the logo does not appear at all. Even when I haven't started scrolling down @emmanuel
I also just tried it right now and it doesn't load up from the start

Comment: There's a trick for making a logo change when the page scrolls: http://www.impressivewebs.com/stationary-logo-changes-page-scroll-css/   Doesn't fit your case perfectly because both versions of the logo are the same size, but perhaps you could modify the technique to serve your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish.
If you're trying to hide the cupcake once you scroll down, this can be done with javascript in a pinch (using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)):

```
$(window).scroll(function (event)
{
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0)
    {
        // If the user is no longer at the top of the page, hide the cupcake
        $("#SwoleCakesPicLogo").hide();
        // Show the small cupcake here...
    } else
    {
        // If the user returns to the top of the page, show the cupcake
        $("#SwoleCakesPicLogo").show();
        // Hide the small cupcake here...
    }
});
```

However, this looks very jumpy and ugly. You can actually change the size of the cupcake ***with and animation*** like this:

```
var factor = 2;
$(window).scroll(function (event)
{
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0)
    {
        // Shrink the cupcake
        $("#SwoleCakesPicLogo").animate({
            top: '+=' + $(this).height() * factor,
            left: '+=' + $(this).width() * factor,
            width: $(this).width() / factor
        });
    } else
    {
        // Grow the cupcake
        $("#SwoleCakesPicLogo").animate({
            top: '-=' + $(this).height() / factor,
            left: '-=' + $(this).width() / factor,
            width: $(this).width() * factor
        });
    }
});
```

***This is sudo-code. Don't just copy & paste it. I haven't tested it. Write or modify your own.***
This code can easily be adapted to what you're trying to accomplish. Refer to the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try make the img hidden instead:

```
 visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: I put visibility:hidden and the it does not show up still